# android recyclerview going through my edit text search filter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` inside a `fragment` with a search filter edit text above it, and when I scroll the recyclerview go through the edit text, but I want the `RecyclerView` always to be under the edit text and leave the edit text on top like a header or something like that no matter how much I scroll. How can I achieve that?

[image: image showing the issue]

code:

the layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".fragments.FoodListFragment">


<com.steelkiwi.library.view.BadgeHolderLayout
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:elevation="100dp"
    app:bhl_badge_radius="10dp"
    app:bhl_default_badge_background="@color/five"
    app:bhl_text_color="@android:color/white"
    app:bhl_text_size="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/capsule_shopping_cart"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_shopping_cart" />


</com.steelkiwi.library.view.BadgeHolderLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_foodlist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/food_list_search_input" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/food_list_search_input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_input_style"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="search"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

the class

```
public class FoodListFragment extends Fragment {

EditText etSearchInput;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private FoodListAdapter foodListAdapter;
private BadgeHolderLayout badgeHolderLayout;
private List<Food> foods;

public interface ListenerFoodListFragment {
    void sendToCart(int value, int adapterPosition);

    void cartClickListener();
}

private ListenerFoodListFragment listenerFoodListFragment;

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        listenerFoodListFragment = (ListenerFoodListFragment) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d("FoodListFragment", "onAttach: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public FoodListFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_list, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_foodlist);
    badgeHolderLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    etSearchInput = view.findViewById(R.id.food_list_search_input);
}




@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    foods = new ArrayList<>();


    foods.add(new Food("Chicken", "99999$", R.drawable.chicken));

    badgeHolderLayout.setOnClickListener(v -> listenerFoodListFragment.cartClickListener());

    foodListAdapter = new FoodListAdapter(getActivity(), foods, listenerFoodListFragment);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(foodListAdapter);

    etSearchInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            foodListAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

}

public void updateCartValue(int value) {
    badgeHolderLayout.setCountWithAnimation(value);
}
```

}

Comment: Set `android:layout_height` of your `RecyclerView` to 0dp to make top/bottom constraints working

Comment: i did it, but nothing changed!

Comment: can you post the entire layout code?

Comment: @hsm59 it's the entire layout !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fixed it by changing my layout to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview_foodlist"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/food_list_search_input" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/food_list_search_input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/search_input_style"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/search_icon"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="search"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<com.steelkiwi.library.view.BadgeHolderLayout
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:elevation="100dp"
    app:bhl_badge_radius="10dp"
    app:bhl_default_badge_background="@color/five"
    app:bhl_text_color="@android:color/white"
    app:bhl_text_size="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/capsule_shopping_cart"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_shopping_cart" />


</com.steelkiwi.library.view.BadgeHolderLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` from your `Recyclerview`
and then Set `android:layout_height` of your `RecyclerView` to `0dp` will works.

Further more add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/recyclerview_foodlist"` in search `EditText` or it may be due to background drawable file you added in search `EditText`

Comment: someone in the comments said this too, and even now my recyclerview look like this https://pastebin.com/hCFzYaqw
it still doesn't work

Comment: only change the height not the width as told by Ghulam

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur i changed the width to `match_parent` but it still didn't work, what the width has to do with it anyway as the problem is in height

Comment: @GhulamQadir will the attributes change didn't fixed it, but what you mean " it may be due to background drawable" ?

Comment: Yes, As i didn't know what script u write in background drawable file but if something wrong still lies there than it may be due to that drawable file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a ConstraintLayout.

`match_parent` will ignore your constraints.

You need to replace the `layout_height="match_parent"` of the RecyclerView with `layout_height="0dp"`. Same for its width.

Then it will be underneath the EditText as you expect.

Comment: this is really weird, i tried this and the app looks fine at the start like this 
https://i.imgur.com/nodKQPn.png

then when i scroll now the `EditText` get hidden by the `RecyclerView` like this
https://i.imgur.com/Eiu5hS4.png

Answer (score -1):

Change your `recyclerview` height to `wrap_content`

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And remove all this code in `recyclerview`

```
android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/food_list_search_input"
```

At last paste this two line in `recylerview`

```
 app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/food_list_search_input"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/food_list_search_input"
```